# consulta error 404 axios y react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, axios

hola chicos como va? intento consumir un endpoint echo en node con express desde un front con react y me arroja 404....pero desde postman la respuesta es exitosa esta tokenizado....esta es la peticion desde el front:

```
login = async () => {
    console.log(this.state.form.email, this.state.form.password);
    await axios.post(url, { params: { email: this.state.form.email, password: this.state.form.password } })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar la direccion del servidor que pones en Postman y la que tienes como varible `url` en la peticion de axios

Comment: hola samuel lo paso....http://localhost:8000/user/login

Answer (score 2):

Cuando obtienes el error 404 es generalmente que no existe el recurso que intentas obtener, en este caso tratas de realizar una peticiòn a el valor de `url`.

Asegura que la variable `url` ya que contiene una url incorrecta o no contiene valor y esta es la causa del problema.

```
 await axios.post(url, { params: { email: this.state.form.email, password: this.state.form.password } })
```